# How green are Ubuntu and Canonical?

Tags: power-management, canonical, environment

im a student of Environmental Engineering, currently searching for a Bachelor Thesis Theme.
I am curious, if there any internal information about Ubuntu related to CO2/Energy saving compared to other Operating Systems.

and what Canonical does for the Environment/sustainability in the offices, during the work etc, in general.

Thank you so much!

Greeting from Lisbon

Comment: I would love to know that to...

Comment: I would be interested in your results if you got anywhere with your thesis. Can you contact me with this?

Comment: they used to be orangishbrown, now they are more purple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a question you should ask someone officially at Canonical.
It would definitely look better if you need to list your sources for the bachelor thesis to have official corporate data rather than some answers you got on a forum, right?

Here's a link to the Canonical contact page. You'd propably want to write to their PR department first. http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact